# How to login using serverspec using ssh key?

Tags: serverspec

[The serverspec doc](http://serverspec.org/advanced_tips.html) indicates that it is possible to login using ssh and serverspec:

> ```
> require 'highline/import'
>
> if ENV['ASK_LOGIN_PASSWORD']
>   options[:password] = ask("\nEnter login password: ") { |q| q.echo = false }
> else
>   options[:password] = ENV['LOGIN_PASSWORD']
> end
>
> set :ssh_options, options
> ```

How to login using an ssh key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serverspec is using [this Ruby class](https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Config.html) to ssh to servers

One should set the path to the key into the ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host X
    HostName X
    User Y
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Z
```

Now `rake spec` runs the test on the server.